# How to apply app shell architecture in ASP.NET Core web page?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to apply an app shell architecture to a test app in ASP.NET core 2.0. I try to keep things very simple to test performance changes when implementing PWA features in this test app. Therefore I use the WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA NuGet package to set up my PWA features.

Now have been struggling for a while to find out how I can apply an app shell which can be cached, while some dynamic content - in my case simple partial views - is still loaded from the network.
The documentation for the NuGet package explains a different caching strategies, but not this one in particular. However, the information on the CacheFingerprinted strategy suggests that it should be possible with this one:

> This strategy is useful for scenarios in which you don't wish to cache
>   certain resources -- large video or audio files, for example -- but
>   still wish to cache the app core assets (HTML, CSS, JS).

It is done by like this:

> This strategy only adds fingerprinted resources (resources with a v
>   querystring parameter such as `site.css?v=8udsfsaufd09sud0809sd_ds) to
>   the cache.
>
> It will always try the cache for fingerprinted resources, then fall
>   back to the network. For all other resources, it will use the network.

But how would I add the fingerprint to my index.cshtml or layout.cshtml? Plus, I wonder how this would even work, since a browser won't be able to make use of a cshtml file.

Moreover, If I try to cache my dynamic content (which is a cshtml file since it's a partial view) with a caching strategy that stores all page content, I assume the html itself is not cached, while the image files it contains are.

My (yes, very basic) Ajax request is set up like this:

I have a partial view called `partialView1.cshtml`.
My HomeController contains

```
public IActionResult partialView1()
{
      return View();
}
```

and my Ajax call within my index.cshtml is the following

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  url: '@Url.Action("partialView1")',
  success: function (result) {
  $('#partialID1').html(result);
  }
});
```

and refers to a simple empty div

```
<div id="partialID1"></div>
```

So since my dynamic content is nowhere called by its filename, how would I be able to cache this with the fingerprinted method?
I have read about returning cshtml from ASP.NET as html strings, but still I would not know how to approach caching it then.